# Error when assigning currentScale of SVG root element

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I have a problem with SVG and JavaScript:

This code behaves as expected:

```
function initSvg(width) {
    SVGRoot = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    console.log(SVGRoot.currentScale);    // Displays '1' which is OK
```

but when I try to reassign the currentScale parameter like so:

```
function initSvg(width) {
    SVGRoot = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    SVGRoot.currentScale = parseFloat(width)/400;   
    console.log(SVGRoot.currentScale);    // Should display some floating point number
```

I get the error

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) nsIDOMSVGSVGElement.currentScale]
```

and the alert is not executed. What is wrong with my assignment to SVGRoot.currentScale?

UPDATE:

The error disappears when I use

```
SVGRoot.setAttribute('currentScale', parseFloat(width)/400);
```

or

```
SVGRoot.setAttributeNS(null, 'currentScale', parseFloat(width)/400);
```

but the actual value of currentScale does not change. It stays at 1 regardless what is passed into setAttribute.

Comment: are you sanitizing the `width` parameter? print its value prior to using `parseFloat` to check if the division is applicable.

Comment: Well, I checked with typeof(parseFloat(width)/400) which evaluates to 'number'. Isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setAttribute(NS) way isn't correct, there's no 'currentScale' attribute in SVG.

The 'currentScale' is a property in the [SVGSVGElement interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement), and you should be able to get and set it like you do as long as the number is reasonable (e.g not Inf or NaN). Note however that the SVG 1.1 spec only defines the behavior of [currentScale](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__currentScale) on the outermost svg element.

Comment: So SVGRoot.currentScale = value is correct, after all. On the very first call the width parameter was indeed NaN. When I filter this case everything is fine.